# Recover data from pixel 4a with black screen

Tags: data-recovery, broken-screen

I have a Pixel 4a with completely damaged screen (it's 99% black) after falling. I can see it's on and ready to use as I recognize the background color and glimpses of things moving through the spots that still show color.

All the options I found online require using the screen of the phone to project the screen on to PC, which is completely useless in this situation.

Is there a way to get access to the OS or data? Can I remove the screen and magically plug it in a monitor with some convertor? What are my options?

[image]

Comment: What means 99% black, are some pixels still working? Has the device enabled developer options and adb? What lock screen is set?

Comment: The screen was damaged when falling. A purple / black splotch grew slowly over a period of a month. Some pixels on the top edge of the screen are still working. While the splotch was growing I had time to enable developer options (and I think ADB) and removed the screen lock.

Comment: I added a picture for reference.

Comment: If you have working adb you can copy all files from shared storage to yozr PC. For app exports use scrcpy o control the phone from PC. You may want to enable Google cloud backup and may be you can try to establish an adb wireless connection. That would allow you to connect the phone to your new phone and use direct Android device migration while at the same time look at the screen via scrcpy via adb over Wifi.

Comment: My phone doesn't show up on my PC when plugged in. I tried scrcpy but not working. It's not detecting the phone.

Comment: On a Windows PC you need to manually install the adb drivers. Without adb does not work and thus scrcpy can not work.